# jsPDF with AutoTable not working - Possible JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a simple example table that I want to download as a PDF. I followed the AutoTable document on getting setup here: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

I didn't know how to create the actual download hyperlink so I tried something with JavaScript and am getting a ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I would prefer to use a standard hyperlink.

My code is as follows:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="downloadPdf">Download Table as PDF</button>

<script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<script>
$("#downloadPdf").click(function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF()
    doc.autoTable({ html: '#myTable' })
    doc.save('table.pdf')
})
</script>
```

Comment: you have to import jquery if you use $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import jquery file, working example - https://jsfiddle.net/nishantj/bja0fnve/

It's downloading a pdf, working as expected. Used the cdn versions of the scripts involved.

```js
$("#downloadPdf").click(function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF()
    doc.autoTable({ html: '#myTable' })
    doc.save('table.pdf')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.6/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="downloadPdf">Download Table as PDF</button>
```